# Meteor camera - permission denied on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, meteor

I have created a small app on `MeteorJS`, which is using the camera at some point to take pictures.
To do so, I just use the `mdg:camera` package.
It all works fine on my `localhost:3000`

Now the problem came when I deployed the app to meteor (xxx.meteor.com)
When testing it, when I try to launch the camera, Chrome complains with

```
Camera permission denied
```

Without asking me first if I want to allow or block the camera.

They suggest going to :

```
Go to Settings > "Show advanced settings..." > "Content settings..." > Media heading > "Manage exceptions...", then find this website in the list and allow video capture.
```

After going there, I can see my `localhost:3000` being allowed, but that's it. I can't find any options to add manually any new exceptions.

Would any of you had this issue ? Is it a `Meteor` issue, where the settings are not set properly, or a `Chrome` settings issue ?

PS : if that helps, here is how I use the camera (I take the picture and save it in session):

```
var options = {
    width: 350,
    height: 350,
    quality: 75,
};

MeteorCamera.getPicture(options, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    }
    if (data) {
        img = Session.get('img');
        if( typeof img == 'undefined') {
            img = [];
        }

        img.push( {hash: (Date.now() / 1000 | 0), data: data});
        Session.set('img', img);
    }
});
```

**Update**
I have tried on `Opera`, camera works fine. It first complains that the permission is not right, but it gives me at the same time a popup to allow or block the camera. After clicking on Allow, the camera works fine.
On `Chrome` even with removing the cookies (maybe the preference would be saved in one ??), still no luck.